# C# & CLIPS. Using .clp in more than in one Form

Tags: c#, clips

I want to use a `.clp` file in my C# project. This project contain several Forms.
Can I load `*.clp` once and use it in all forms (create/delete facts, etc.)?
(I am using `CLIPSNet.dll`.)

UPD. There is a Form1. On close it I save the facts. In second form (Form2) I want to do same thing but if I load a .clp file in block of Form2 I've lost the facts entered at first form. 
How I can avoid this situaton? So I need opened CLIPS file through all C# solution. So I want ask you - Is it really to do or not?

UPD1. I use MVS Community 2013.

Comment: What does rly? mean?

Comment: I'm sure you can pass a reference to a ClipsNet object to all forms that need one.

Comment: Is it really what? Please clarify your question, including the title.

Comment: You don't mention how you're saving the facts. If you've saved them, then you can just reload them if you have to reload the .clp files for whatever reason. As the other comment suggests, however, just create one CLIPSNet object that's used by all the forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Dude, just create another class working with CLIPS project!
  That's it.**